# Do uncertainty relations for charge or mass exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, charge, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Is there a uncertainty relation for charge $q$ of the form
$\Delta q \Delta? \geq \hbar$ in quantum mechanics? From checking the units ($[q] =  A\cdot s$) I guess that $?$ would have to be the [magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux) $[\Phi] = V \cdot s$, so we would have
$$
\Delta q \Delta \Phi \geq \hbar
$$
If I play the same game with mass $m$ the units would suggest a uncertainty relation
$$
\Delta m \Delta \Phi_g \geq \hbar
$$
where $[\Phi_g] = \frac{m^2}{s}$ is the gravitomagnetic flux (which happens to have the same units as the [kinematic viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Kinematic_viscosity_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000012-QINU.60.22.27.7F), the [specific angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_relative_angular_momentum), the [mass diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_diffusivity) and the [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity)).

Do these two uncertainty relations exist in quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding electrical charge the answer is definitely negative: In Quantum Mechanics there exists a so-called *superselection rule of the charge* which requires that the charge is always definite in every quantum state of any  quantum physical system carrying electrical charge. So $\Delta q_\psi =0$ in every state $\psi$ and no Heisenberg relations are possible for whatever choice of a conjugated variable of $q$.

Regarding mass, in non relativistic QM the situation is identical: There is an analogous superselection rule (Bargmann's superselection rule).

In the quantum relativistic realm, for elementary systems the mass observable is actually a Casimir operator and thus, again it is always defined.

For composed systems or non-elementary relativistic systems, the situation is more delicate, but I think the only possibility to define some notion of mass is just the Hamiltonian observable defined with respect to a preferred reference frame *at rest with the system*. This way one immediately faces the problem of *time-energy uncertainty relations* which do not have a well-defined status in QM, since there is no self-adjoint operator representing the time observable (this is the so called Pauli's theorem).

Comment: Does this imply that there must also be a superselection rule for the conjugate variable (magnetic or gravitomagnetic flux) in non relativistic QM?

Comment: No, exactly the contrary: as $\Delta q=0$, for the conjugate variable we would have $\Delta X = +\infty$ and thus no state at definite $X$ may exist in contradiction with a superselection rule for $X$.